# Typeahead twitter bootstrap not functioning mvc4

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter, typeahead

I am trying to implement this code [here](http://jcherryhomes.com/post/2012/12/03/ASPNET-MVC-Using-Twitter-Bootstrap-Typeahead-via-Ajax.aspx)

but I get no results while running the project.

here is my code:

View:

```
<input type="text" name="names" value="" id="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead"                autocomplete="off"  />
```

Again on view (index.cshtml):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (term, process) {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/index/GetNames")';

                return $.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {
                    return process(data);
                });
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Controller (indexController.cs):

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetNames(string term)
{
    // A list of names to mimic results from a database
    List<string> nameList = new List<string>
    {
        "Jonathan", "Lisa", "Jordan", "Tyler", "Susan", "Brandon", "Clayton", "Elizabeth", "Jennifer", "Hadi"
    };

    var results = nameList.Where(n =>
        n.StartsWith(term, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    return new JsonResult()
    {
         Data = results.ToArray(),
         JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    };
}
```

here are also the js scripts added at the end of the view page:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.intellisense.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

here is also the list of bugs I get on runtime:

- `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bootstrap.js:29`
- `Uncaught ReferenceError: intellisense is not defined jquery-1.9.1.intellisense.js:1`
- `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'typeahead'`

Please let me know what am i doing wrong!

Comment: Good thing we took the time to answer this one for you so you could leave us hanging without an accepted answer. -_-

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit old but you cannot use `source:` you must use either `remote:`, `prefetch:`, or `local:` as the error reads.

Which version of bootstrap are you using?  The standalone plug-in no longer supports all of the different data providers in the same way as the old one did

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you place the script tag referencing jquery first, before bootstrap. Also only load a single jquery script tag.

Like this:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: right! js errors solved but now a new problem: Uncaught Error: one of local, prefetch, or remote is required

Answer (score 0):

All the JS libraries you are using at the moment have one dependancy: `jQuery` so they need to be loaded in right order:

```
<!-- jQuery should always be the first -->
<!-- jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery-1.9.1.min.js are the same but .min version is minified and always lighter, so use it for faster page load -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Any other library should be loaded after jQuery -->
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.intellisense.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Ok I've made those changes and the problem with above errors solved but I still get this: Uncaught Error: one of local, prefetch, or remote is required in jquery-1.9.1.min.js I think its something to do with the data fetching for the typeahead. the method GetNames never gets a call!

Comment: Are you including the library http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/ ? If so, you should remove the reference to it since Bootstrap already contains another typeahead function and the 2 of them are a bit different.

Comment: Hieu, No i'm not including any libraries referring to twitter.github.io/typeahead.js. Still same error: Uncaught Error: one of local, prefetch, or remote is required. I know that it means i must pass at least one data source (prefetch or remote) or a data set (local) but im doing that in the GetNames functions and calling it via the jscript !!